# How can I decode intercepted gRPC requests/responses to view the sent/received protobuf messages in golang?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I am intercepting the raw gRPC requests/responses going across a UNIX socket (the containerd socket using the [cri-api](https://github.com/kubernetes/cri-api), using eBPF to perform the interception) and I want to work out what is being sent/received. I have access to the [.proto](https://github.com/kubernetes/cri-api/blob/master/pkg/apis/runtime/v1alpha2/api.proto) file used to generate the gRPC interface using the [gRPC plugin](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go/#generate-grpc-code) so this should be possible to do but I'm not sure how to start as I am not part the gRPC connection.

How can I go about doing this in golang?